# Add values to legend with bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Is it possible to put the values of the pieces of the pie chart next to their names in the legend?

Example:
You have a pie chart counting the number of apples, pears and oranges.
15 apples, 10 pears and 13 oranges.
The legend looks like this:
Apple, Pear, Orange

Is it possible to make it look like this?
Apple 15, Pear 10, Orange 13

Thanks

I looked online a bit but didn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [piechart example code](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/pie_chart.html) to create this example. I created a new column in the dataframe that contains the name of the legend.

```
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Category20c
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

output_file("pie.html")

x = {
    'Apple': 15,
    'Pear': 10,
    'Orange': 13
}

data = pd.Series(x).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'fruit'})
data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*pi
data['color'] = Category20c[len(x)]
sep = []
for i in range(len(data.index)):
    sep.append(': ')
data['legend'] = data['fruit'] + sep + data['value'].astype(str)

p = figure(plot_height=350, title="Pie Chart", toolbar_location=None,
           tools="hover", tooltips="@fruit: @value", x_range=(-0.5, 1.0))

p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.4,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='legend', source=data)

p.axis.axis_label=None
p.axis.visible=False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```